# Private nuget package not appearing in packages folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have a .NET Core web application with a reference to a .NET Standard 1.2 private NuGet package.

When I reference the package from the code It directs me to the local `c:\users...` folder. But the package doesn't exist in the local root/packages folder.

So the problem is that when I try to build from the build server, the package doesn't appear in the coot/packages

I tried everything, including a package restore.

Any ideas?

Comment: By Private Nuget you mean you have a Private Nuget server, where you host binaries and you are able to find the package in the "Manage Nuget references", but couldn't actually refer it, did you get your private Nuget repository does it actually contains the binary and what's the settin where will it restore

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj of course, we use it all the time, this is the first time it happends

Answer (score 0):

As found here: [dot net standard ref issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481)

The issue is happening when referencing a dotnet standard project from a dotnet core project. 
A work around is adding the dotnet standard project as reference of a dotnet framework project